# Have 2 gateways, need each to provide a DNS through itself

Tags: domain-name-system

I have 2 gateways, and I need each of them to each provide its own automatic DNS server, which would be automatically, exclusively accessed through it.

Both gateways are connected to the same LAN segment. By Automatic DNS I mean the gateways are to provide each its own DNS address to the other devices on the network, where each device is configured to automatically fetch the available DNS addresses from the gateways.
The reason for my weird requirement is that one of the gateways provides me with access to a corporate network, where the DNS responses are restricted and all I can do is work against corporate servers. The other gateway is connected both to a different infrastructure and Internet Service Provider, where no known restrictions are applied. So for the corporate services I need its own DNS (since all its records are corporate private) and for the rest of the world I need access to an unrestricted DNS.

Comment: You really need to flesh this out, why are you doing this, what is automatic DNS, and where are the gateways connected, to a single LAN, multiple LANs, etc?

Answer (score 1):

As Paul says, you will need a DNS relay to send requests to the upstream servers, how you decide on which server the client will talk to will be the difficult issue. With Bind9 you can create a relay server fairly easily, then you will just need to tell the clients looking for domains that correspond to the corporate servers to talk to the corporate DNS, anything else will be sent to the ISP servers.

```
options {
directory “/var/cache/bind”;
allow-query { any; };
allow-recursion { any; };
query-source address * port 53;
forwarders {
172.17.0.5;  <-- make this the ISP DNS server(s)
};
auth-nxdomain no;
listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
zone "corporate.com" IN {
forwarders {
192.11.0.5;  <-- make this the corporate DNS server(s)
};
};
```

This may not be correct syntax wise (it's probably missing some important pieces), and set up like this it isn't particularly secure, but hopefully it's enough of an example to get you started.

Comment: I could, of course, resort to manual settings of the DNS Servers' addresses. The question remains, though, how software behaves when the primary DNS returns a valid negative response: would the TCP/IP stack attempt to sound out the secondary DNS, nevertheless?

Comment: If it returns a not found, it could try the second one.. you'll probably want to test it.

Comment: I had done some more in-depth search and concluded that by and large DNS clients would cache any DNS response even if the response is negative. Only if a DNS query times out, will the client attempt another go at the alternative. However, according to DNS clients' practical implementation, DNS clients typically query DNSs in a round robin order, or a similar fashion thereof. That means that there is no "Primary" nor "Secondary" DNS servers, as I initially assumed. Now I face the difficulty of each of my DNSs providing different functionality: they are equal in principle, but not in practice!

Comment: Which is why I suggested the forwarder, you set a single server that forwards to A or B based on domains (any domain in the corp you forward to the corp, anything else goes to the ISP).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bind9, so your suggestion didn't make much sense to me. Would you care to further elaborate on the issue or point me to a worthy and helpful tutorial?

Comment: Certainly, sorry, bank weekend. This is a perfect tutorial to explain.. http://gleamynode.net/articles/2267/

Comment: @user171941, i think you are misunderstanding DNS. It's not the gateway that the traffic goes through which determines which DNS server it should use, but the other way around. DNS provides a single-root namespace, so if you want corporate.com to go via your corporate gateway, then you should direct requests for that domain to that domain's internal name server on the DNS server that your clients use as their primary. You only need one DNS server, configured something like Nick has suggested. It doesn't need to run on the gateways - it could be another box entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, you might want to look at pfSense or Vyatta, which provide a gateway function in an appliance.  Both of them include dnsmasq, a popular DNS caching relay server.